# ¿Cómo leer los datos de un archivo en textbox desde una clase?

Tags: c#, windows-forms

el problema que tengo es el siguiente: necesito por medio de una clase, leer los archivos para ordenarlos en texbox.

este es el método que esta en la clase mencionada:

```
public string Leer(string id, string n, string c)

    {
        
        string error = "";
       
        try
        {
            string linea = "";
            string[] m;
            StreamReader rd = new StreamReader ("Datos.txt", true) ;
            linea = rd.ReadLine();
            while (linea != null)
            {
                m = linea.Split('#');
                if (id == m[0])
                {
                    n = m[1];
                    c = m[2];
                }
                
                linea = rd.ReadLine();
            }
            rd.Close();
 

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            error = ex.Message;
        }
        return error;
    }
```

Y este es el que esta en la clase del formulario:

```
private void btnleer_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string error;
        Mantenimiento M = new Mantenimiento();
        error=M.Leer(txtID.Text, txtNombre.Text, txtCorreo.Text);


        if (error != "")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("error a leer", "Leer", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
       
    }
```

Al ejecutar dicho código no me envía el mensaje de error indicando que esta correcto, sin embargo no me muestra dicha información en los textbox, ¿Se necesita cambiar algo en algún procedimiento? Muchas gracias.